# Why can I open the Root Terminal only once? [Debian 9]

Tags: debian, terminal, root

I freshly installed Debian 9.0 with Cinnamon and for some reason I can only open the root terminal once (after I start up the PC).

When I try to open it up a second time it doesn't show: when I press OK after entering the correct administrative password the screen just shortly flickers black and nothing happens (besides the password-window getting closed of course). It also flickers black when I press cancel without entering anything.

I have "Remember password" unchecked (albeit having had it checked once).

**Edit:** this might be relevant - earlier (maybe due to having it checked once) I once got this message when opening up Synaptic:

> The '/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator' program was started with the
> privileges of the root user without the need to ask for a password,
> due to your system's authentication mechanism setup.
>
> It is possible that you are being allowed to run specific programs as user root without the need for a password, or that the
> password is cached.
>
> This is not a problem report; it's simply a notification to make sure you are aware of this.

**Edit:** I'm new to Linux so I'm not sure which logfiles I should look into and what to look for. When I try to open the root terminal a 2nd time I get this in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Successful su for root by myuser
+ /dev/pts/1 myuser:root
pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
```

I closed the root terminal before that by pressing its X close button.

With "Root Terminal" I'm referring to that shortcut with the red screen as icon. The usual terminal works just fine (with `su`).

Comment: What happens when you enter a regular terminal and run 'su'. Can you get it?

Comment: @MichaelBruce Yes! That works (even multiple times). Thank you - that basically answers half of my question (I'm still new to Linux).

Comment: The reason is probably in some log file.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but I'm not sure which and what to look for (as said I'm new to Linux/Debian). I looked into `/var/log/auth.log` where I find that session is created and closed "for user lightdm" before I login to my account but I guess that's normal (I could find some search engine entries on this)? I added the log entries for when I try to open it a 2nd time above.

Comment: @Arrow Have you deleted your answer here? Why? You could restore from: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PpBF01EzcDYJ:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372764/why-can-i-open-the-root-terminal-only-once-debian-9    Also it closes correctly by the X-close button but I still can't open it up again after closure.

Comment: @Arrow and reinstalling gnome-terminal (tried it via synaptic with all terminals closed first) didn't help either. The 2nd time I try to open the screen just flickers black and nothing happens. It might be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

It is an [old bug in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712104) that is not going to be fixed any time soon, considering the [last message](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712104#85) from Simon McVittie, on the 4th of July 2017, quoting:

> The gksu package (gksu, gksudo commands and the "root terminal"
>   launcher) should be considered deprecated, and hasn't been touched
>   since
>   2014. We should probably remove it from Debian before Debian 10.
>
> Running gnome-terminal (or any graphical program, really) as root is
>   not really something that is supported any more.  gnome-terminal
>   segfaulting (signal 11) when run like this is clearly a bug and should
>   in principle be fixed, but it is unlikely to be anyone's highest
>   priority.
>
> Best practice is to run as much as possible (in particular all GUIs)
>   as an ordinary user, and use sudo, pkexec, su -, ssh root@localhost or
>   your favourite similar tool to escalate privileges where necessary.

(note: `gksu` is what is actually used to launch `gnome-terminal` with the root user when you click on "Root terminal")

So, [as already advised by Michael Bruce](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372769/203203), open a classic terminal and type `su` or `su -` (the latter being preferable IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

Open a normal terminal and type 'su'. This should get you to root access. We can delve farther on your issue once this is clear.

Comment: Can you open your /usr/share/applications folder and look at the properties of the GUI your are using?  does it say `sudo <application_name>` or `gksudo`??

Comment: How do I look at the properties of the GUI I'm using? As I understand it by rightclicking Cinnamon->Properties? But I couldn't find anything of that sort in its properties nor anywhere in the title of the window so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: in the basic terminal type `ls /user/share/applications/*terminal`, what do you see/

Comment: I imagine you have gnome-terminal. Either way, on your desktop pres Alt-F2. A diolog box should pop up and type `gksudo <flavor>-terminal`. Flavor being the name of yours such as `gnome`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: In the properties of "Terminal" under `/usr/share/applications/` it says "gnome-terminal". I have Cinnamon installed. When I enter `gksudo gnome-terminal` there and enter the correct administrative password I only get a loading mouse for 2 sec. (And I restarted my PC before trying. When trying the same with sudo instead of gksudo nothing happens.)

Comment: what is the output of this? `cat /etc/locale.gen | grep -v "#"`

Comment: `de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8` and 2 newlines above it

Comment: I am not familiar with Debian, I have used Arch Linux exclusively for almost a year. But, try setting up your locale. Look for something in your configuration settings. Certainly, Cinnamon has some sort of GUI. Just give it a shot. Sometimes these are locale issues.